# Quand est-ce qu'on écrit "er" ou "é" à la fin

Tags: orthographe, infinitif, participe-passé

D'après la question on a comme exemple:

> Réalisé par:

et

> Transférer à:

Comment peut-on faire la différence pour écrire "é" ou bien "er"?

Comment: Juste pour information, il y a une espace insécable avant les demi-points (entre autres).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Réalisé par**  est une forme passive elliptique*.

Prenons le cas d'un diaporama, on pourra y mettre en générique :

> Réalisé par AB.

ce qui est la forme réduite de

> Ce diaporama a été réalisé par AB.

L'objet dont on parle (le diaporama) **subit l'action** faite par AB.

**a été réalisé** est une forme passive qui se forme avec le verbe être (au temps qu'on a choisi, ici le passé composé) suivi du participe passé du verbe (ici réalisé).

**Transférer à** est une directive/une instruction elliptique.

Prenons le cas d'un document que j'envoie à quelqu'un en lui mettant une note :

> Transférer à BC après lecture.

ce qui est la forme réduite de :

> Pouvez-vous transférer à BC après lecture.

ou

> Il faut (merci de) transférer à BC après lecture.

Après « pouvoir », « il faut », « merci de » ... on met l'infinitif. **Transférer** est une action dont BC sera l'**acteur** (le sujet).

<sub>*  dont il manque un morceau.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

La forme en é correspond au participe passé. Cette forme se veut une description de son objet ("la pomme mangée"). La forme en er est l'infinitif du verbe utilisé. C'est donc souvent sous forme d'instruction ou d'indication qu'on l'utilise ("mesurer la farine").

Un truc souvent donné pour éviter cette erreur est de remplacer le verbe avec la terminaison en er par un verbe ayant une autre terminaison et utiliser celui qui fait le plus de sens ("la pomme mordue" et non "la pomme mordre", donc "la pomme mangée et non "la pomme manger"). Ce truc est par contre moins applicable à celui dont le français est une langue seconde parce que l'instinct du bon remplacement ne sera pas là.

Answer (score 0):

Si vous parlez couramment, mais vous ne savez pas toujours les règles de grammaire et d'orthographe, ce qu'on m'a appris à l’école était de songer à comment on dirait la phrase, si le verbe était conjugué comme « finir » au lieu de comme « aimer » : parce que, avec «finir », on peut facilement **entendre** la différence entre l'infinitif (qui est « finir ») et le participe passé (qui est « fini »).

Donc par exemple on dirait,

> Fini par:

Et,

> Courir à: